# How to compare values from 2 date sets in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, compare

I want to calculate 3 fields: start_count, new_count, end_count, completed_count 
where

```
count = no.of Item_ids  
start_count = previous day's end_count  
new_count = current day's count (item ids which are not present in previous day)  
completed_count = start_count - no.old item_ids
end_count = start_count + new_count - completed_count
```

df:

```
Date    Item_id    Count
    01/01/2020    100    1   
    01/01/2020    101    1   
    01/01/2020    100    1    
    02/01/2020    102    1    
    02/01/2020    101    1    
    02/01/2020    100    1    
    03/01/2020    101    1    
    03/01/2020    102    1    
    03/01/2020    103    1
```

df_result:

```
Date    Start_count    new_count    completed_count    end_count
01/01/2020    3    3    0    3
02/01/2020    3    1    1    4
03/01/2020    4    1    2    3
```

I tried:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()  
for d in dates:  
    if df.Item_id[d] in df.Item_id[d-1]:      
        df_calc['old'] = df.groupby('Date').agg({'Count':'sum'}).reset_index()  
        if not df_Item_id[d] in df.Item_id[d-1]:  
            df_calc['new'] = df.groupby('Date').agg({'Count':'sum'}).reset_index()  
    else:  
        df_calc['old'] = 0  
df2.append(df_calc)
```

and got error:
`datetime.date(2020,1,1)`

Comment: What is the error, and which line is causing it?  Look at the traceback.

Comment: 3rd line of the code..

Comment: But what is the type of exception?  (eg ValueError, IndexError, TypeError, etc)

Comment: `df.Item_id` is a list? It looks like you're using a `datetime.date` object to index a list.  That's not going to work.  TypeError.  Indices need to be integers.

Comment: is there a way of checking if a value exists in previous date in such an example? That would really help!

Comment: You're trying to compare an element of a list to the previous element in that list?  `lst[i] == lst[i-1]` where `i` is the index of the latter element. Looks like you were using `in` to check for equality, but that checks for membership.